# Parser Error in IFrame When added in Application Page

Tags: 2013, application-pages, iframe, parser-error

I am creating a **`SharePoint-2013`** web-part in that I have created **`Application Page`**.

In that page I am using **`<iframe>`** element only there are no any other elements just for testing. But it is giving me ***error*** like:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The base class includes the field 'frame1', but its type (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlIframe) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl).

Source Error:


Line 364:                <tr>
Line 365:                    <td>
Line 366:                        <iframe id="frame1" frameborder="0" runat="server" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="200px" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" visible="false"></iframe>
Line 367:                    </td>
Line 368:                </tr>


Source File: /_layouts/15/OpportunityViewWP/MasterPage.aspx    Line: 366

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

Below is the *screenshot*.

[image: Parser Error Message]

But when I am adding the same `<iframe>` in `Visual-Web-Part` it works properly.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem.?

Thanks in advance...!!

Answer (score 1):

Go to your .cs designer file.

Change:
`protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl FinalScoreframe;`
To:
`protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlIframe FinalScoreframe;`

Will solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0"/>
```

to

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

Comment: I am new to sharepoint hence want to know where I can find 'targetFramework' attribute. I have checked web.config under VirtualDirectories\<port> but not able to find the respective attribute.